# Identifying the most representative observation in a sample

Tags: distance, social-network

Given a multidimensional **X**, is there a standard way of identifying the most representative observation? A few options come to mind:

1. Minimum average distance (e.g. cosine, Mahalanobis) from all other observations.
2. Minimum distance from multidimensional center of sample (for certain distance measures I think this would be equivalent to (1)).
3. Maximum centrality (e.g. PageRank) from a social network analysis, where edge weights are inverse to some distance measure.

Comment: What's your objective? Do you want every measure of central tendency listed here?

Comment: You will have to pin down what you mean by "most representative" -- why not the mode? What about the center of the smallest region containing half the data?

Comment: Multidimensional measures of central tendency (mode doesn't seem to be an option for multidimensional data) seem to be half the problem (except if taking an SNA approach), with the second being calculating observations' distances from that center. Part of my objective is at least understanding if there's other terminology or concepts that relate to this, as initial Googling didn't return much.